# Facebook switched us from Live to In Development because the app is in beta

Tags: android, facebook, development-environment, production-environment

So, we have an app that has a website (`production`), an app (`production`) and a new app (`beta`).

The problem is that all applications but the recent one are production.

Briefly, the `Facebook` alert said (regarding the package name that is in `beta`):

> The corresponding URL(s) should return a successful HTTP status code. You can verify this using the Sharing Debugger. - Compliant response codes: 200-299 - Violating response codes: 100-199, 300-399, 400-499, 500-599

We got switched from `Live` to `In Development` because of that.

Now, the question is:

What should we do next? What would it happened if we keep our status (dev mode) even with production products? There are not that many options here. We cannot set our app to public until closed beta testing is done.

Comment: So you are talking about an Android app? Then the URLs the message is referring to can only be the website or privacy URL, I suppose? Make sure those are publicly available and respond with a success status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you all find it useful.

Considering you have the icon, privacy policy, all information requested by Fb and you receive notification above, consider:

If you have plenty other apps (web, android, ios, any) and them all are live. Your Fb app should be live too.

If your brand new app is not yet visible (e.g. beta testing), means basically that all your Fb id should returned to in development (according to Fb. Although, your prod apps will stop working).

So, what you can do is, create a specific app which is in development when the others are live. Or, like in our case, we removed Android on Fb from the website (will turn that on again when beta testing is done) and issue got solved at that moment.